# How to generate a Map from a list of keys and one value?

Tags: dart

I'd like to create a `Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>>` from a list of keys and a unique value to obtain this:

```dart
        final snearkerBrand = {
          "addidas": shoeSettings,
          "nike": shoeSettings,
          "new balance": shoeSettings,
          "le coc sportif": shoeSettings
        };
```

I tried this without the desired result:

```dart
        
        final snearkerBrand = {
          [
            "sneaker",
            "boot",
            "others",
          ]
          .map((brand) => e: shoeSettings)
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```dart
final shoeSettings = <String, dynamic>{ ... };

final sneakers = <String>[
  'addidas',
  'nikes',
  'new balance',
  'le coc sportif',
];

final sneakerBrand = <String, Map<String, dynamic>>{
  for (final sneaker in sneakers)
    sneaker: shoeSettings,
};
```